# Is it possible to create an application in Qt which rotates the image based on Motion Sensor?

Tags: qt, qt4, qimage

I have a MPU 6050 chip, from which I get the accelerometer (X, Y, Z) and gyroscope (Pitch, Roll, Yaw) reading. How to rotate a 3D image by using these accelerometer and gyroscope reading in Qt, any sample project or example? Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the best way would be the OpenGL widget from QT.

You can find good OpenGL tutorials here: [NeHe](http://nehe.gamedev.net).
An entry point for OpenGL in QT is here: [QtOpenGL](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qtopengl.html)

The rest: reading the input from your device and loading the 3d-image is up to you. It greatly depends on the device & the format of your 3D-Image. Regarding the 3D-Image: check NeHe's Tutorials.